# Unable to run flutter app in Android Studio on iOS simulator. No problem on Android tablet

Tags: android, ios, gemfile

Launching lib/main.dart on iPhone SE (3rd generation) in debug mode...
Warning: CocoaPods is installed but broken. Skipping pod install.
You appear to have CocoaPods installed but it is not working.
This can happen if the version of Ruby that CocoaPods was installed with is different from the one being used to invoke it.
This can usually be fixed by re-installing CocoaPods.
To re-install see https://guides.cocoapods.org/using/getting-started.html#installation for instructions.

CocoaPods not installed or not in valid state.
Error launching application on iPhone SE (3rd generation).

---

I have many things: un-install all cocoapods, then sudo gem install cocoa pods

I have also restarted AS many times while trying different fixes, still not resolved.

when I do "pod --version" it returns error:
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.3/Gemfile not found

I also did "ruby --version"
124 ruby 2.6.8p205 (2021-07-07 revision 67951) [universal.arm64e-darwin21]

I am using MacAir M1 chip, 2020, Android studio BumbleBee 2021.1.1 Patch 3
Please help!